# ¿Cómo cargar datos mysql en un select html? -php

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

seguí una serie de pasos para poder cargar el nombre completo de un usuario en la opción de un select, no me marca error pero no me los muestra de igual forma ¿Qué tengo mal?

```
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "constructora");

if (!$conexion) {
    echo 'Error';
} else{
    echo 'Conectado';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Nomina</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Nomina</h2>

<h3>Aqui va ir el nombre del empleado para acceder a sus datos especificos</h3>


<div class="nomina">

    <form action="consulta_nomina.php" method="post">
        <label for="empleado">Empleado</label>
<select name="empleado" id="id_empleado">
            <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT id, nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno FROM empleados";

while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<option value="'.$valores[id].'">'.$valores[nombre].''.$valores[apellido_paterno].''.$valores[apellido_materno].'</option>';
}
            ?>

</select> <br/>
<label for="puesto">Categoria</label>
<select name="categoria" id="puesto">
            <option value="1">Peon</option>
            <option value="2">Albañil</option>
            <option value="3">Maestro de obra</option>
        </select>
        <br/>

<label for="fecha_de_pago">Fecha de pago</label> 
<input type= "text" name="fecha_de_pago" id="fecha_de_pago"/> <br/>

<label for="dias_laborados">Salario diario</label> 
<input type= "text" name="salario_diario" id="salario_diario"/> <br/>

<label for="dias_laborados">Dias laborados</label> 
<input type= "text" name="dias_laborados" id="dias_laborados"/> <br/>

<label for="dias_laborados">Salario total semanal</label> 
<input type= "text" name="salario_semanal" id="salario_semanal"/> <br/>

<label for="dias_laborados">Salario total sin iva</label> 
<input type= "text" name="salario_total_sin_iva" id="salario_total_sin_iva"/> <br/>

<label for="dias_laborados">Descuento por extravio</label> 
<input type= "text" name="descuento_por_extravio" id="descuento_por_extravio"/> <br/>

<input type="submit" value="Crear"/>

    </form>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te faltan comillas en los indices de el array $valores asi: `$valores['id']`

Comment: Ya he puesto comillas en los indices del array pero sigue igual

Comment: Te falta el parametro de conexion en `mysqli_fetch_array`  Deberia ser asi: `while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($conexion, $query)){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero que traigas los valores desde la Bd ya concatenados, asi:

```
<?php 

  $sql = "SELECT id, CONCAT(nombre, ' ', apellido_paterno, ' ', apellido_materno) AS nombres FROM empleados";

  $query = $conexion -> query ($sql);

  while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     echo "<option value='".$valores['id']."'>".$valores['nombres']."</option>";
  }

?>
```

espero te sirva, nos cuentas!

Comment: Sirvió perfectamente

Comment: Me alegro mucho bro...